# Flipping k adjacent coins from n coins laid on a circle to make them all head-up

Tags: number-theory

Think of $n(\geq3)$ coins laid on a circle, each showing head-up or tail-up. The goal is to make every coin head-up by flipping $k$ adjacent coins several times.

What is the necessary and sufficient condition of $n$ and $k$ for achieving this goal from any starting state?

For example, I show an example below, where $n=4, k=3$:
[image]
('O' means head)

I figured out two conditions by invariant:

1. $k$ should be odd
2. $k \nmid n$

But I'm stuck showing whether this is an if and only if condition.

Comment: you can get there in 2 for this start state.  select oxo and flip, then xxx flip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is about the question whether the set of $n$ vectors
\begin{align}
\{x\in \mathbb{F}_2^n: x \text{ is a cyclic permutation of } (\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{k},0,\ldots,0)\}
\end{align}
is a basis of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ or not. Therefore, it is enough to check whether the circulant matrix with first column $(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{k},0,\ldots,0)$ is singular or not.

Assume that this circulant matrix is invertible. Then,
\begin{align}
\text{gcd}(1+x+\ldots+x^{k-1},x^n-1) =1
\end{align}
(See **Corollary 10** in [ON CIRCULANT MATRICES](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/pdf/cir-not5.pdf), In this link, circulant matrix over $\mathbb C$ is described but it also holds for $\mathbb{F}_2$ since the inverse of circulant matrix on the finite field is again circulant by Cramer's rule).

Since
\begin{align}
\text{gcd}(1+x+\ldots+x^{k-1},x^n-1) &=\text{gcd}(1+x+\ldots+x^{k-1},1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1}) \\&= 1+x+\ldots+x^{\text{gcd}(n,k)-1}
\end{align}
for odd $k$,
and
\begin{align}
(1+x)|\text{gcd}(1+x+\ldots+x^{k-1},x^n-1)
\end{align}
for even $k$, the if and only if conditions are

1. $k$ is odd,
2. $n,k$ are coprime.