# flipping K coins laid on a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In this question on the flipping of k adjacents coins : [Flipping k adjacent coins from n coins laid on a circle to make them all head-up](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332691/flipping-k-adjacent-coins-from-n-coins-laid-on-a-circle-to-make-them-all-head-up)

I want a demonstration for the first part of this answer :
[image]

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote a state by $\mathbf{x}$. Then flipping $k$ adjacent coins is equivalent to adding a vector $\mathbf{e}_i=(0,\ldots,0,\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_k,0,\ldots,0)$.

For example, in the original question, going from the first to the second state is equivalent to $(1,0,1,0)+(1,1,1,0)=(0,1,0,0)$.

Since addition is commutative, flips can be performed in any order, and since $\mathbf{e}_i+\mathbf{e}_i=\mathbf{0}$, a specific flip need only be done once.

The problem written as vectors is to determine $\alpha_i\in\{0,1\}$ such that $$\alpha_1\mathbf{e}_1+\cdots+\alpha_n\mathbf{e}_n+\mathbf{x}_0=\mathbf{0}$$ which is equivalent to saying that $\mathbf{e}_i$ span $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, i.e. whether they form a basis.

Comment: Denote a state by x , how many states are valid from the 2^n possible states

Comment: $\sum_i\alpha_ie_i$ span a sub-space $M$, so $F^n$ partitions into classes $x+M$. (Special case: $M=F^n$, when all vectors are reachable from $x$).